# How to add an object to an armature to make it movable?

Tags: mesh, objects, armature, bones

I have a model with an armature, the objects inside of which move according to the trajectory of the bones. But there is also an object (Shorts) that I tried to attach to the armature in the same way as other objects (Ctrl+P), but no matter what I do, it remains in place.

What do I need to do to make it move with both legs and in different directions?

Thank in advance for the answer.

[image: example]

Comment: Before joining the short to the rest of your character, parent it With Automatic Weights, give it some corrections in Weight Paint mode if necessary, then join (Ctrl J) to the rest of the character.

Comment: @moonboots Hello, I did as you recommended, but nothing has changed.

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Unfortunately, I could not upload the file to this site because there is a size limit. https://www.mediafire.com/file/9iejpxu2s4xhnuj/Body.blend/file 
Perhaps you can also tell me how to connect objects to the second model? When I connect them using Armature Deform, they rotate or change their positions, and I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this kind of armature settings, I hope someone will help. Also you should apply the scale of armature and object, and lower down the density of the object, it's very high-poly and it may be the reason why the parentage fails